# Cleaning up data written from BeautifulSoup to Text File

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-files, python-requests

I am trying to write a program that will collect specific information from an ebay product page and write that information to a text file. To do this I'm using BeautifulSoup and Requests and I'm working with Python 2.7.9.

I've been mostly using this tutorial ([Easy Web Scraping with Python](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-python)) with a few modifications. So far everything works as intended until it writes to the text file. The information is written, just not in the format that I would like.

What I'm getting is this:

```
{'item_title': u'Old Navy Pink Coat M', 'item_no': u'301585876394', 'item_price': u'US $25.00', 'item_img': 'http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxMjAw/z/Sv0AAOSwv0tVIoBd/$_35.JPG'}
```

What I was hoping for was something that would be a bit easier to work with. 
For example :

```
New Shirt 5555555555 US $25.00 http://ImageURL.jpg
```

In other words I want just the scraped text and not the brackets, the 'item_whatever', or the u'.

After a bit of research I suspect my problem is to do with the encoding of the information as its being written to the text file, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

So far I have tried,

```
def collect_data():
        with open('writetest001.txt','w') as x:
                for product_url in get_links():
                        get_info(product_url)
                        data = "'{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}'".format(item_data['item_title'],'item_price','item_no','item_img')
                        x.write(str(data))
```

In the hopes that it would make the data easier to format in the way I want. It only resulted in "NameError: global name 'item_data' is not defined" displayed in IDLE.

I have also tried using  `.split()` and `.decode('utf-8')` in various positions but have only received AttributeErrors or the written outcome does not change.

Here is the code for the program itself.

```
import requests
import bs4

#Main URL for Harvesting
main_url = 'http://www.ebay.com/sch/Coats-Jackets-/63862/i.html?LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=1000&_ipg=24&rt=nc'

#Harvests Links from "Main" Page
def get_links():
        r = requests.get(main_url)
        data = r.text
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)
        return [a.attrs.get('href')for a in soup.select('div.gvtitle a[href^=http://www.ebay.com/itm]')]


print "Harvesting Now... Please Wait...\n"
print "Harvested:", len(get_links()), "URLs"
#print (get_links())
print "Finished Harvesting... Scraping will Begin Shortly...\n"


#Scrapes Select Information from each page
def get_info(product_url):
        item_data = {}
        r = requests.get(product_url) 
        data = r.text
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)

        #Fixes the 'Details about  ' problem in the Title
        for tag in soup.find_all('span',{'class':'g-hdn'}):
                tag.decompose()
        item_data['item_title'] = soup.select('h1#itemTitle')[0].get_text()

        #Grabs the Price, if the item is on sale, grabs the sale price
        try:
                item_data['item_price'] = soup.select('span#prcIsum')[0].get_text()
        except IndexError:
                item_data['item_price'] = soup.select('span#mm-saleDscPrc')[0].get_text()

        item_data['item_no'] = soup.select('div#descItemNumber')[0].get_text()

        item_data['item_img'] = soup.find('img', {'id':'icImg'})['src']

        return item_data

#Collects information from each page and write to a text file
write_it = open("writetest003.txt","w","utf-8")

def collect_data():
        for product_url in get_links():
               write_it.write(str(get_info(product_url))+ '\n')

collect_data()
write_it.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track.
You need a local variable to assign the results of `get_info` to.  The variable `item_data` you tried to reference only exists within the scope of the `get_info` function.  You can use the same variable name though, and assign the results of the function to it.

There was also a syntax issue in the section you tried with respect to how you're formatting the items.

Replace the section you tried with this:

```
for product_url in get_links():
    item_data = get_info(product_url)
    data = "{0},{1},{2},{3}".format(*(item_data[item] for item in ('item_title','item_price','item_no','item_img')))
    x.write(data)
```